# Http 404 when access the MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have an MVC application. I am routing to a controller using HTTP post method. When I am running the application in the local machine (using VS ) it works fine. But when I deployed it and access through a link its not working.

I used fiddler to debug the routing. It specifies following error.

```
No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.
No WWW-Authenticate Header is present.
```

I used windows authentication and configured the IIS also as same. In the same application the GET methods are working fine.

Comment: What does your controller code look like?  What URL are you using?

Comment: it is POST /Potential/UpdateStatus HTTP/1.1